# JQuery: как выборочно обработать уход курсора с блока?

Tags: jquery

Добрый день. Пытаюсь изобразить меню, при наведении на `div` вниз выпадает  другой `div` (подменю).

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('.nav__cli').hover(function() {
      $('.nav__sub_cli').show(); 
          });
    $('.nav__cli').mouseleave(function() {
        $('.nav__sub_cli').hide(); 
        });
 });
```

Само собой, когда курсор уходит с пункта меню, подменю исчезает.
Меню горизонтальное, то есть если мы уводим курсор на соседний пункт или вверх, подменю должно исчезнуть, а если переходим на него - естественно, остаться и исчезнуть, если курсор в сторону уходит уже с блока подменю.
Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: вложить `nav__sub_cli` в `nav__cli`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, в идеале делать так, чтобы пункт меню и подменю были внутри одного элемента, на котором в css вешать :hover https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/3kqovnaf/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
 <a href="#" class="menu-item">Пункт меню с выпадалкой</a>
 <div class="undermenu">
   <a href="#" class="undermenu-item">Подпункт 1</a>
   <a href="#" class="undermenu-item">Подпункт 2</a>
   <a href="#" class="undermenu-item">Подпункт 3</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.undermenu {
  display: none;
}
.parent:hover .undermenu {
  display: block;
}
```

Но если такой возможности нет, то идет как у вас, только при mouseleave надо делать небольшую задержку перед закрытием подменю https://jsfiddle.net/skywave/f5wh52qy/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timeout;
    $(document).on('mouseover', '.menu-item, .undermenu', function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout); // при наведении чистим timeout, чтобы не закрылся
    $('.undermenu').addClass('show');
  });
  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.menu-item, .undermenu', function(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.undermenu').removeClass('show');
    }, 500);
  });
});
```